# How to access android /data/data database using SQLite?

Tags: java, android, mobile, android-2.2-froyo

I have written a code using DataBaseHelper class, i make a database using SQLite and place it in assets, then this helper class copies it into /data/data/mynamespace/databases, but if i insert values using SQLBrowser in SQLite db which is in assets folder, then i read it using code, but i dont find those inserted values, but if i insert it using code, i can see my values inserted, i understood it in such a way that assets and /data/data are two separate copies, but question is, how can i browse data using SQLite Database Browser from /data/data/mynamespace/databases/mydb file. Because that is the actual db, in assets there is just a copy, please let me know its solution.

Comment: people can just rate negative, but dont have answer for problem, may be i am wrong or asking wrong but let me correct if you know.

Comment: I think your question was rated negatively because it is not clear. Try to reword it in a way that would show the problem and the question, and just that.

Comment: Try posting some example lines of code where you copy the database and open it.

Comment: Suggest that you need to use more than 2 sentences in your 'question'. Perhaps in the future use a question mark somewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [this article](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/) he reads a SQLite file from the `assets` folder and copies it to `../../data/databases` folder.

I am using this code and its' working fine for me.

Comment: yes i took help from this tutorial, but when it copies it into /data/data folder then if i read, it shows empty record.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your copy operation is either failing or going to the wrong place.

So when you try to access the database it is just being created instead of opened.